# Getting static variables from a string

Tags: ios, swift, string, static, initialization

I have the following class that describes a country:

```
class Country: NSObject {

    public var name: String

    static let england = Country(name: "England")
    static let scotland = Country(name: "Scotland")
    static let allCountries = [england, scotland]

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init?(named name: String) {
        guard let country = Country.allCountries.filter( { $0.name == name } ).first else { return nil }
        self.init(name: country.name)
    }

}
```

To get the constant `Country.england`, I would use:

```
let england = Country.england
```

**However**, I want to be able to get this constant from a `String` using `convenience init?(named name: String)` as follows:

```
let england = Country(named: "England")
```

This seems a little clunky and this code initialises a new "`england`" instance rather than taking the static one.

**Is there a more Swifty way of doing this?** Ideally I'd like to just let `self = country` in the `convenience init?(named name: String)` function, but I get the error **cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: KVC with literal strings is not *Swifty* at all .

Comment: Pro tip - use `.first(where: { $0.name == name } )` rather than `.filter( { $0.name == name } ).first`

Comment: @AshleyMills thanks for the tip

Comment: @vadian touché ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about writing a `named` factory method instead?

```
static func named(_ name: String) -> Country? {
    return Country.allCountries.first(where: { $0.name == name } )
}

// usage:
let england = Country.named("England")!
```

The initializer approach could be used if `Country` were a struct:

```
struct Country {

    public var name: String

    static let england = Country(name: "England")
    static let scotland = Country(name: "Scotland")
    static let allCountries = [england, scotland]

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    init?(named name: String) {
        guard let country = Country.allCountries.filter( { $0.name == name } ).first else { return nil }
        self = country
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning towards this being the better way, but it would look nicer to initialiser it rather than call a class function in my opinion...

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis You could use an initialiser if `Country` were a struct. See the edit.

Comment: That was my next question - does it need to inherit from `NSObject` and does it need to be a `class?

Comment: @AshleyMills I'll look into structs. Perhaps it doesn't need to inherit from `NSObject`. `Country` just needs to be equatable and have a bunch of `UI*` objects.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Country` only has a `name` then you would be better off using an enum…

```
enum Country: String, CaseIterable {
    case england = "England"
    case scotland = "Scotland"
}

Country(rawValue: "Scotland") // Optional(scotland)
Country(rawValue: "Wales")    // nil
```

Note `CaseIterable` is Swift 4.2+ but allows you to write `Country.allCases`

```
Country.allCases  // [england, scotland]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The original post is more of a minimal working example. The class is more complicated than just having one variable.